# How can you "copy" a range of data if a value is entered?

Tags: excel

I made a few tables and I want to **move** the table to a place if a value is entered in a cell. I have put here an example. So, I want to make it that if I put number `1` in C3 the `A14:B17` table is copied in `A5:B8`

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I code below code will do what I think you want.
Note:
Rather than 'move' the table values, it 'places' the required values
If you literally meant 'move', let me know (in comments below) and I will amend

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rgChanged As Range)

    Dim inC%, inRows%

''' The 'control' is cell C3
''' To move the control, change the Address value here (keeping the $ signs)
    If rgChanged.Address = "$C$3" Then
        
    ''' Address of source Table is A14:H17:
    ''' Change the address here to match the size and location of the table
        With Range("A14:H17"): inRows = .Rows.Count
            
        ''' Find class entered in the table (setting inC to match colunm)
            For inC = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2
                If .Cells(1, inC) = rgChanged Then Exit For
            Next inC
            
        ''' If not matched, report and end
            If inC > .Columns.Count Then
                MsgBox "Invalid Class Number", vbInformation, "Class Selection"
                Exit Sub
            End If

        ''' Transfer the values to target area starting at Cell A5
        ''' To move the Target starting cell, change the Address value here
            Range(Range("A5"), Range("A5").Offset(inRows - 1, 1)).Value = _
                Range(.Cells(1, inC - 1), .Cells(inRows, inC)).Value
            
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

The above goes to the vba of the sheet. if you don't know what that means, let me know (by commenting below) and I will explain.